# Unable to mount External hardisk

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/fctbth/TOSHIBA EXT 2: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdb2" "/media/fctbth/TOSHIBA EXT 2"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read of MFT, mft=6 count=1 br=-1: Input/output error
Failed to open inode FILE_Bitmap: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

please anyone can help me for solved this problem..

Comment: is the device a raid or ntfs drive?

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message! It tells you what to do: `In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important!`

`NTFS` is an undocumented Microsoft Windows filesystem. This problem is NOT fixable under Ubuntu.

Comment: ok thnkyu, but i had run **chkdsk /f** on windows but i have message error **chkdsk is not available for RAW drives**

i dont have idea, think i can solved this problem on ubuntu.

Comment: You can't solve it in Ubuntu. You may format it again (all data lost) if there's no other damages. But if you want NTFS then that also is better done in Windows.

Comment: Hi I had the same situation, when i used a HDD with an adapter via USB2. When I put the HDD in a tower, I could read the files again. - No Idea what's wrong